# How can I optimize a DateTime conversion based on a user timezone?

Tags: php, performance, datetime

This is the function I have written, it works fine except for the fact that it has the potential to be called hundreds of times, causing some speed bottlenecks. I want to know if there is a way to optimize this code to be more efficient in regards to execution time.

```
    /**
 * Takes in the airing values, and then converts them to user local time, giving back the day, dayname, and a formatted timestring.
 * The Day is an ISO calendar day of the week, Hour is a 24-hour format hour, and Minutes is the minutes
 * @param int $airing_day The airing day (1-7)
 * @param int $airing_hour The airing hour (0-23)
 * @param int $airing_minutes The airing minutes (0-59)
 * @return array The Array of values with keys ['day', 'dayname', 'timestring']
 */
public static function airingTimeToUserTimezone($airing_day, $airing_hour, $airing_minutes)
{

    // February 1st the 2016 is a monday, perfect for conversion, since we can correlate 1 to Monday and 7 to Sunday
    $AirDateTime = new DateTime('2016-2-' . $airing_day . ' ' . $airing_hour . ':' . $airing_minutes . ':00');
    $AirDateTime->setTimezone(self::$user->DateTimeZone);

    $toret               = array();
    $toret['day']        = $AirDateTime->format('N');
    $toret['dayname']    = $AirDateTime->format('l');
    $toret['hour']       = $AirDateTime->format('G');
    $toret['minutes']    = $AirDateTime->format('i');
    $toret['timestring'] = $AirDateTime->format("g:i A");

    return $toret;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried simulating the environment to check whether it will really behave as slow as you expect?

Comment: I never received any feedback regarding the answer I left; did it solve your problem? If it did, marking it as accepted would be appreciated; thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless this is going to executed thousands of times a second, you probably aren't going to see much of a performance hit from this function. However, one optimization I see is to call `DateTime::format()` only once:

```
public static function airingTimeToUserTimezone($airing_day, $airing_hour, $airing_minutes)
{
    $AirDateTime = new DateTime("2016-02-$airing_day $airing_hour:$airing_minutes:00");
    $AirDateTime->setTimezone(self::$user->DateTimeZone);

    $toret = array();
    list (
        $toret['day'],
        $toret['dayname'],
        $toret['hour'],
        $toret['minutes'],
        $toret['timestring']
    ) = explode("/", $AirDateTime->format("N/l/G/i/g:i A"));

    return $toret;
}
```